# Finding where a specific number appears in an expression

Tags: pattern-matching

I would like to see how many times (and where) the number "91" appear in a set of formulae.

I thought of using `Position[expr , 91 , Infinity]`, but it seems not to be working in this simple example:

```
Position[{Log[Sqrt[1 + I Sqrt[-1 + (4 mm)/91]]]}, 91, ∞]
```

which gives

`{}`

Why?

Comment: At first glance this feels like it could be a bug. Report to WRI Support to see what they say.

Comment: @Edmund. If you look at the `FullForm` of this expression, the `91` is embedded inside `Rational[4,91]`, and it seems like the pattern matcher is treating anything that looks like `Rational[_,_]` as atomic (which might or might not be intended behavior). Indeed: `Cases[Rational[4, 91], 91, Infinity]` evaluates to `{}`. The work-around of Alexei's below is a reasonable hack, although annoying that it must be done.

Comment: Interestingly, `Cases[Rational[x, 91], 91, Infinity]` evaluates to `{91}`, indicating that the pattern matcher sees actual numbers in the form `Rational[_, _]` as atomic, but if the expression is symbolic, it does not.

Comment: @march. `Rational[x, 91]` is not an atomic expression, so it is treated differently from `Rational[4, 91]` which is atomic.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
expr = Log[Sqrt[1 + I Sqrt[-1 + (4 mm)/91]]];
Position[expr, f_[x_, 91] | f_[91, x_]]

(*  {{1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1}}   *)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 4):

```
expr = {Log[Sqrt[1 + I Sqrt[-1 + (4 mm)/91]]]};
```

If you look at the [`FullForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) of the expression, you see that `91` appears only inside [`Rational`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rational.html)

```
expr // FullForm
```

[image]

Since `Rational` is an atomic element ([`Atomic Elements of Expressions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/AtomicElementsOfExpressions.html)), the `91` is not accessible by `Position`. However, you can see the position of the `Rational` containing `91` as shown by Alexei.

```
Position[expr, Rational[_, 91], ∞]

(* {{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1}} *)
```

There are no parts to an atomic expression.

```
Rational[4, 91][[-1]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An alternative pattern to search through the atoms:

```
Position[Log[Sqrt[1 + I Sqrt[-1 + (4 mm)/91]]], _?AtomQ[___, 91, ___] | 91]
```

> {{1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1}}

Also

```
Position[Log[Sqrt[1 + I Sqrt[-1 + (4 mm)/91]]], 
 TypeSystem`$AtomPattern[___, 91, ___] | 91]
```

> {{1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1}}

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to change the expression into a string and then locate the string "91" within that. For your example:

```
expr = {Log[Sqrt[1 + I Sqrt[-1 + (4 mm)/91]]]}; 
StringPosition[ToString[expr], "91"]
{{94, 95}}
```

Which shows that 91 occurs in the final two positions of the string.

Comment: While this works, it's rather counter-intuitive that `9` and `1` are the final two characters in the string for that expression.  A naive expectation might be that `]` and `}` would be the final two characters.

Comment: Counterintuitive or not... StringLength[ToString[expr]] is 95.